# tidymodels: error when predicting on new data with xgboost model

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidymodels

I trained two xgboost models. One was trained without resampling calling fit() right after model specifications were made like this...

```
model <- boost_tree() %>%
set_mode() %>%
set_engine() %>%
fit()%>%
predict()
```

.. and it works just fine, my predictions were made.

Another was trained with resampling setting up a workflow with tune::tune_grid(). Once tune_grid trained the model, i selected the best model with tune::select_best(), finalized the workflow with tune::finalize_workflow() and extracted my final model with a fit() call on the trainning data and lastly workflow::pull_workflow_fit(). However when i want to make predictions with these model on new data, the following error shows up:

```
Fehler in xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data = newdata, missing = NA) : 
  'data' has class 'character' and length 1178.
  'data' accepts either a numeric matrix or a single filename.
```

In both cases the new data is a exactly the same tibble. Anyone knows an answer to this problem?

Comment: run `class(newdata)`: is it a numeric matrix? if the format isn't correct you can try coercing it with `as.matrix` perhaps. If you have characters in then perhaps its categorical variables that need encoding. In https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/vignettes/discoverYourData.html section 1.2.2.3 talks about this

Comment: ``class(newdata)`` was "tbl" at first. After performing ``as.matrix()`` it gives "matrix" but the error stays the same. The training/testing data do not contain any character feature, but factor features. I fed the model a "tbl" as it is only accepting "tbl" as data format. Nevertheless, when i want to predict on new data it says: "data accepts either a numeric matrix or s single filename" as stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used one of the `tune_*` functions to find the best parameters for your model and then finalized your workflow with those parameters, the next step is to **train** or fit that workflow one more time on the whole training set. Let's walk through an example.

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.1 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.7.0      ✓ recipes   0.1.13
#> ✓ dials     0.0.8      ✓ rsample   0.0.7 
#> ✓ dplyr     1.0.0      ✓ tibble    3.0.3 
#> ✓ ggplot2   3.3.2      ✓ tidyr     1.1.0 
#> ✓ infer     0.5.3      ✓ tune      0.1.1 
#> ✓ modeldata 0.0.2      ✓ workflows 0.1.2 
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.2      ✓ yardstick 0.0.7 
#> ✓ purrr     0.3.4
#> ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x purrr::discard() masks scales::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()  masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()     masks stats::lag()
#> x recipes::step()  masks stats::step()

## pretend this is your training data
data("hpc_data")

xgb_spec <- boost_tree(
  trees = 1000, 
  tree_depth = tune(), 
  min_n = tune()
) %>% 
  set_engine("xgboost") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

hpc_folds <- vfold_cv(hpc_data, strata = class)

xgb_grid <- grid_latin_hypercube(
  tree_depth(),
  min_n(),
  size = 5
)

xgb_wf <- workflow() %>%
  add_formula(class ~ .) %>%
  add_model(xgb_spec)

xgb_wf
#> ══ Workflow ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Formula
#> Model: boost_tree()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> class ~ .
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Boosted Tree Model Specification (classification)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   trees = 1000
#>   min_n = tune()
#>   tree_depth = tune()
#> 
#> Computational engine: xgboost

doParallel::registerDoParallel()
set.seed(123)
xgb_res <- tune_grid(
  xgb_wf,
  resamples = hpc_folds,
  grid = xgb_grid
)

xgb_res
#> # Tuning results
#> # 10-fold cross-validation using stratification 
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    splits             id     .metrics          .notes          
#>    <list>             <chr>  <list>            <list>          
#>  1 <split [3.9K/434]> Fold01 <tibble [10 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  2 <split [3.9K/434]> Fold02 <tibble [10 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  3 <split [3.9K/434]> Fold03 <tibble [10 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  4 <split [3.9K/434]> Fold04 <tibble [10 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  5 <split [3.9K/434]> Fold05 <tibble [10 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  6 <split [3.9K/434]> Fold06 <tibble [10 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  7 <split [3.9K/433]> Fold07 <tibble [10 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  8 <split [3.9K/432]> Fold08 <tibble [10 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#>  9 <split [3.9K/431]> Fold09 <tibble [10 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
#> 10 <split [3.9K/431]> Fold10 <tibble [10 × 6]> <tibble [0 × 1]>
```

Next, let's finalize this workflow and then `fit()` it to the training data. (The tuning process used the training data, but that was to find the best model parameters, not to train the model itself.)

```r
trained_wf <- xgb_wf %>%
  finalize_workflow(
  select_best(xgb_res, "roc_auc")
) %>%
  fit(hpc_data)

trained_wf
#> ══ Workflow [trained] ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Formula
#> Model: boost_tree()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> class ~ .
#> 
#> ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> ##### xgb.Booster
#> raw: 2 Mb 
#> call:
#>   xgboost::xgb.train(params = list(eta = 0.3, max_depth = 3L, gamma = 0, 
#>     colsample_bytree = 1, min_child_weight = 9L, subsample = 1), 
#>     data = x, nrounds = 1000, watchlist = wlist, verbose = 0, 
#>     objective = "multi:softprob", num_class = 4L, nthread = 1)
#> params (as set within xgb.train):
#>   eta = "0.3", max_depth = "3", gamma = "0", colsample_bytree = "1", min_child_weight = "9", subsample = "1", objective = "multi:softprob", num_class = "4", nthread = "1", validate_parameters = "TRUE"
#> xgb.attributes:
#>   niter
#> callbacks:
#>   cb.evaluation.log()
#> # of features: 26 
#> niter: 1000
#> nfeatures : 26 
#> evaluation_log:
#>     iter training_merror
#>        1        0.320942
#>        2        0.301778
#> ---                     
#>      999        0.010390
#>     1000        0.010390
```

Now let's say we have some brand new data. You can `predict()` with new data on the trained workflow.

```r
brand_new_data <- hpc_data[5, -8]
brand_new_data
#> # A tibble: 1 x 7
#>   protocol compounds input_fields iterations num_pending  hour day  
#>   <fct>        <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
#> 1 E              100           82         20           0  10.4 Fri

predict(trained_wf, new_data = brand_new_data)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   .pred_class
#>   <fct>      
#> 1 VF
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank You for the extensive answer. Following your instructions with my own data, Predicting with the trained workflow object works just fine. However this seems not so traceable for me that i call ``predict()`` on ``trained_wf`` instead of ``trained_wf %>% pull_workflow_fit()`` which gives me an actual parsnip model object.

Since predicting the following way, i call ``predict()`` on a parsnip model object still

``boost_tree() %>%
set_mode() %>%
set_engine() %>%
fit()%>%
predict()``